# Issues in caching internal SQLITE rowid in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, rowid

I am working on an android 2.3.3 application which uses **SQLITE** as the DB.I am currently using the **internal *ROWID* in sqlite** to update my rows and retrieve data.I recently found out that the internal ROWID changes for my rows at times.I don't know the reason for this.The problem is that i am caching this ROWID to later perform an update operation.So in case the ROWID changes i might be updating the wrong row.

I think there are two solutions to this.

(1)Prevent the internal ROWID from changing(which i don't know how to acheive).Also can someone let me know what is causing this ROWID change?

(2)Define an  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column and use that as the ROWID.

Let me know if it's possible to prevent the rowid change or else i will adopt the second solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using INTEGER PRIMARY KEY for the row id.

Can you post the table definition you're using now? The value you're using shouldn't change unless a) you're changing it or b) you've defined it in some strange way.

Comment: As i mentioned i am using the sqlite internal rowid

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is  a process in your app, that compress the DB (vacuum) and this could change the rowid's if there are deletions before that compress performs

Comment: my app doesn't have any processes.Don't know if there are internal processes in the OS that does this.

Comment: I now understand what you're doing. You should read the the SQLite documentation on internal ROWID, to see if it applies to your situation: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html. You may be deleting the row with the maximum ROWID value, which will cause the ROWID algorithm to behave in unexpected ways.